# AM/PM issue in NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsdateformatter

I write below code to convert one date format into another dateformat.
But AM string works and PM did not work .
Please help-

```
dateTime=@"2013-01-24 18:30 PM";
//dateTime=@"2013-01-24 06:30 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSDate *AptDate=[dtFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *strDate=[dtFormatter stringFromDate:AptDate];
```

Here I get AptDate variable as null if i use PM format

Comment: What is `18:30 PM` ? Either it should be `06:30 PM` or `18:30`

Comment: Oh yes you are ryt...Now I am done with this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `HH` in place of `hh`, as your time is in 24 hour format:

```
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
```

---

Your full code will go as:

```
*dateTime=@"2013-01-24 18:30 PM";
//dateTime=@"2013-01-24 06:30 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
NSDate *AptDate=[dtFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *strDate=[dtFormatter stringFromDate:AptDate];

NSLog(@"===> %@",AptDate);
NSLog(@"===> %@",strDate);
```

Output:

```
===> 2013-01-24 07:00:00 +0000
===> Jan 24,2013 12:30 PM
```

Comment: But it will give output as 12:30 PM and actual time is 6:30 PM not 12:30 PM, and i need 6:30 PM

Comment: Now I am done with this, Just need to remove AM/PM at the end

Comment: Good, anyways if it is 24 hrs format you dont need to use AM/PM. And your 12 hours you can use ` NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    dtFormatter.locale = twelveHourLocale;`

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:400];
NSString *oldDate = [exercise objectForKey:@"date"];
//make formatter
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; //24 hour format
NSDate *tempDate=[formatter dateFromString:oldDate];
NSLog(@"temp date %@", tempDate);
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *newDate=[formatter stringFromDate:tempDate];
NSLog(@"new date %@", newDate);
//make label text
[dateLabel setText:newDate];
```

For anyone looking from mySQL with a DATETIME stamp to a regular hh:mm a format showing AM/PM correctly this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for **Swift 3** version of Accepted answer.

```
let date1            = Date()
let formatter        = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"
print(formatter.string(from: date1))

let dateTime            = "2013-01-24 18:30 PM"
let dateFormater        = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"
let AptDate             = dateFormater.date(from: dateTime)
dateFormater.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"
let strDate             = dateFormater.string(from: AptDate!)

print("===> \(AptDate!)")
print("===> \(strDate)")
```